# Creative commons licensed audio files of basic French vocabulary

Tags: data-request, audio, wiktionary

I'm searching for a dataset that contains an audio file for every word of basic French vocabulary.

[Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/) has files but I don't know how to get them together, so that I don't have to download them separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the pronunciation files on Wiktionary are from the [Shtooka Project](http://shtooka.net/download.php), that offer colllections of audio files for basic vocabulary in many languages, licensed under the [CC-BY](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/) license.